# Help with limit $\displaystyle\lim_{t\to 0^{+ }}\sup_{x\in[0, \infty)} |e^{-t^2-2tx}f(x+t)-f(x)|=0$..

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis

can anyone help me showing $$\displaystyle\lim_{t\to 0^{+
}}\sup_{x\in[0, \infty)} |e^{-t^2-2tx}f(x+t)-f(x)|=0,$$ where $\displaystyle f\in C_0([0, \infty))=\{f\in C([0, \infty)): \lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)=0\}$. The problem is tue supremum because I don't know if that is continuous...What I thoght up to now was using bounding $$\sup_{x\in [0, \infty)}|e^{-t^2-2tx}f(x+t)-f(x)|\leq \sup_{x\in [0, \infty)}|f(x+t)-f(x)|+\sup_{x\in[0, \infty)}|e^{-t^2-2tx}-1||f(x)|,$$ but I got nowhere.. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a nice start! To finish it: Let $\epsilon > 0$. Then use the triangle inequality as you did to get
$$
\sup_{x\in [0, \infty)}|e^{-t^2-2tx}f(x+t)-f(x)|\leq \sup_{x\in [0, \infty)}|f(x+t)-f(x)|+\sup_{x\in[0, \infty)}|e^{-t^2-2tx}-1||f(x)|.
$$

Since $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)=0$, $|f(x)| < \epsilon$ for $x > K$, where $K$ is some constant.

We have that
$$
\sup_{x\in [0, \infty)}|f(x+t)-f(x)| = \max\{\sup_{x\in [0, K]}|f(x+t)-f(x)| , \sup_{x\in (K, \infty)}|f(x+t)-f(x)| \},
$$
and the second term is less than $2\epsilon$ for all $t>0$. The first term is less than $\epsilon$ for $t$ small since we are on a compact interval (which makes $f$ [uniformly continuous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniformly_continuous)).

Similiar considerations take care of $\sup_{x\in[0, \infty)}|e^{-t^2-2tx}-1||f(x)|$.

Comment: I had already got to the right answer, but thanks anyway =D

Comment: Good! You learn more that way :)